# Push new certificate to VPN clients

Tags: vpn, openvpn, nas, certificate

I got a synology NAS on which I host a VPN Server with OpenVPN. The default certificate by synology renews (has to be renewed) every 3 months.

What happens is that every three months all of the vpn clients can't connect anymore because the certificate in the config is outdated.

Is there a way to simultaneously update those certificates or link them somehow that all clients have the correct one every time?

I know I cloud just switch to a different certificate with longer time period, but that would just shift the problem to a later time.

Comment: That doesn’t really sound like a great setup. Maybe look into using a different certificate with OpenVPN or maybe even WireGuard instead.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But it was free and for everything else than the VPN it's enough. Also their support had no "fix" for this. But even if I use a different certificate. At some point I will run in this problem again (just a little bit later) right?